# Weird photo coming up when I publish

Tags: photos, blogger

Sometimes when I publish my blog, a picture of a woman I don't know comes up. It's not me. Other people have told me that when they try to share my blog on Facebook, the same woman comes up. How do I get rid of that photo and replace it with my own?

Comment: I've read your latest blog, and apart from it being a nice blog, I could't see any other woman popup. I checked your google+ photo and all it the same. The issue of 4th of Jan. might cause the problem: http://knownissues.blogspot.com/

Comment: Hi Melinda. I am Ellie. I have a blog on blogspot too. I visited your blog just now, and followed it through to your Google+ profile that you linked to. I didn't see any other woman's photo. I saw your photo, on both Google+ and on your blogger blogspot blog. I don't use Facebook, so I don't know about that. You have a nice blog! I think that @JacobJanTuinstra is probably correct. Let us know if you are still having trouble, okay?